# Moving multiple items between Outlook folders - C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

The task is to move multiple items from one folder to another **without using any loops** (which basically move 1 item at a time and then repeat the process again and again). In fact, I am talking about C# equivalent of choosing multiple items in folder in Outlook and moving them elsewhere. Is there a way of doing this, or am I stuck with loops anyway here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this originating from some test?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can move items without using a loop using EWS API.The `do while` loop used here is to loop through the pages as the `ItemView` has a pagesize of 100. You can change this logic as you wish. But I haven't looped through the `findResults` which is a set of emails.

Here I am assuming that the folder 'Test' is under the root folder. If the folder is a subfolder under Inbox change it to `WellKnownFolderName.Inbox`

```
List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new List<SearchFilter>();
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, searchFilterCollection);

ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject);
view.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow;

FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
do
{
     findResults = service.FindItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox(user)), searchFilter, view);    

     var itemIds = from item in findResults
              select item.Id;

     service.MoveItems(itemIds,
                    (Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot)
                    .FindFolders(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Test"), new FolderView(1))
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DisplayName == "Test")).Id);

      view.Offset = Convert.ToInt32(findResults.NextPageOffset);

 } while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
```

Answer (score 0):

While it would occasionally be nice to be able to move a bunch of messages at once, the simple answer is you can't.

The EWS API does not provide a method for moving a list of messages all at once, only a method for moving an individual message to a different folder.  As such you are stuck with looping through your messages and moving them individually.

Which, incidentally, is how Outlook seems to do it... so in that regard you're at least fulfilling that requirement :)

Comment: Obviously, Outlook does that with some other algorithm than simple loop. If you loop through 100 messages to delete them via item.Delete() it takes about 10 to 15 seconds to iterate through all of them. If you select 100 messages in Inbox and press "Delete" - they go to "Deleted items" almost immediately. That's the mission - to achieve similar performance.

Comment: @Onewinged If you delete a few thousand entries at once it takes time to iterate through them all. It does it fairly quickly, but it's not instant.  If it runs faster it's probably because Microsoft have a closed API that Outlook uses.  They've built all sorts of things like that into their systems over the years, so it wouldn't surprise me to find that Outlook has its own way of talking to Exchange that nobody else can use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a loop like **foreach**, **while** to iterate through the collection of your selected mail items.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method for moving multiple items at once. Use the [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the MailItem class for moving items in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only), [IMAPIFolder::CopyMessages(MESSAGE_MOVE )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765921.aspx) takes a list of entry ids and thus allows to move or copy multiple messages in a single call.

Outlook Object Model however only allows to copy or move one message at a time. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author - any language) is an option, it exposes [RDOFolder.Items.MoveMultiple](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm) / `CopyMultiple` methods that take a list of ";" or CR/LF separated entry ids or an array of entry id or items.